# I need to redirect a drawable in one folder to another folder

Tags: java, android, drawable

I am adding another theme to my launcher theme app.

This particular launcher has the icons in a different folder than all my other launchers.

Currently I have them in my res/drawable-xhdpi folder

But this theme calls for them to be in /assets/theme/icon folder.

Can i put a xml in that folder to redirect to the images in my drawable-xhdpi folder?